# Cannot access element bouding client rect through refs in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, dom, vuejs2

I use an external Vuejs component to render a calendar. Inside this calendar, the display of events is customized by injecting my own components through slots. For some reason I need to get the bounding client rect of these sub-components (actually their root div element). So I set up refs on these divs in MyCustomComponent:

```
<div class="some-style"
     ...
     ref="rootElement">
```

In the parent component ParentComponent, I also add a ref on each of the sub-component to access its root element:

```
<div slot="slot-for-events"
     ...">
    <my-custom-component
        :ref="`ref-${id}`"
        ...
    >
    </my-custom-component>
</div>
```

Then, when hovering over this component, I try to get its coordinate in a method of ParentComponent through:

```
const rect = this.$refs[`ref-${id}`].$refs.rootElement.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log('Rect:' + JSON.stringify(rect));
```

However, the rect that is returned has all its components to zero. This is not a problem with synchronicity as the event is fired way later the component is mounted. This is not a problem with refs not being defined either, as all the refs are correctly defined and rootElement correctly points to a DIV element. This is just getBoundingClientRect() not returning the actual bounding rect.

The strangest thing is that if I add an ID on the very same divs, then typing in the console

```
document.getElementById('ref-' + id).getBoundingClientRect();
```

correctly returns the bounding client rect, for the very same element referenced by the ref rootElement!

Any idea of what is happening there ?

Comment: Try putting a `debugger` statement in just after you grab `rect` so you can really dig in and see exactly what was going on at that moment.